# Setting memcached for lampp on linux using pecl

Tags: php, linux, memcached, pecl, lampp

**ORIGINAL POST**

First of all, I want to install **memcached**, not memcache.

I'm trying to set up memcached to work with my lampp server on ubuntu 12.10 since yesterday. I've already followed almost every tutorial I could find. The most recent thing, I tried to do was:

in terminal

```
apt-get install libmemcached-dev 
cd /opt/lampp
./bin/pecl install memcached
```

and then adding extension="memcached.so" in php.ini file. After this I restarted lampp using `/opt/lampp/lampp restart`

When I tried to open php script in my browser it just got downloaded. Running `tail -20 /opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log`this is what I see:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
```

It seems [this guy](http://montenasoft.com/en/blog/how-install-pecl-php-extension-64bit-linux-while-you-are-using-32bit-xampp) had same problem but with different extension. When I try to compile 32 bit version of the extension using:

```
phpize
CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32 CCASFLAGS=-m32 ./configure
make
```

But `make` throws the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libmemcached.so when searching for -lmemcached
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmemcached
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [memcached.la] Error 1
```

**The problem is that I don't even know if I'm on the right path**. If someone could write short step-by-step guide how to get this working or just show me where the issue is it would be great.

**UPDATE**

After executing `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 sudo apg-get update sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev:i386 libz-dev:i386` and `phpize CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32 CCASFLAGS=-m32 ./configure make` memcached compiles fine. It still doesn't work however. After checking php error logs again I get this

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: The version of the libmemcached library you have installed is 64-bit only, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path - your lampp is 32bit while rest of the system (i assume) is 64bit. So when you installed libmemcached an compiled php-libmemcached it is 64bit version. That's why you get the "Wrong ELF class" error.

Before you can compile 32bit version of php-memchached you need to install 32bit versions of libmemcached and libz (and their headers).

You need to:
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
`sudo apg-get update`
`sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev:i386 libz-dev:i386`

I think that should be enough to let you compile 32bit version of php-libmemcached.

Comment: I managed to compile memcached and now I get a different error in php logs:
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I guess I should install older version of compiler, but how to do this? For example apt-get install g++-4.2.0 doesn't work. I know I'm newbie...

Comment: this error i don't understand :( btw. can you tell why your php is 32bit?

Comment: I don't think there's a 64bit version of xampp at the moment

Answer (score 1):

There is a dirt way to fix your problem

go to `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.x.x`

and copied the libgcc_s.so into

`/opt/lampp/lib` and renamed it to `libgcc_s.so.1` to overwrite the previous file.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I awarded bounty to you, but accepted Raber's answer since I want both of you to get some reputation